# Android layout textview align right xonsidering the maximum size

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, textview

[image]

The first image is what I managed to do.

In the second one I would like to succeed.

I have to put the textview with the text: 01.35 on the right, as seen from the image, considering the maximum extension of the text that could contain the different textview above and below it.

I thought and tried with the relativLayout, but I could not solve the problem.

Some advice?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/widgetItemContainer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/round_message"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ch"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/container2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Alberto"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/username"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:text="@angela"
                    android:textColor="#2d2d2d" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/timestamp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="false"
                    android:text="01.35"
                    android:textColor="#2d2d2d" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/container3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/container2"
                android:text="#ulisse Il piacere della scoperta."
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the width of the parent LinearLayout (the one that contains the 2 TextViews) to match_parent (and its parent as well - i.e. container2). Then use LinearLayout's weights for its children to balance them out. Something like:

```
<LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:weightSum="1"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/username"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:text="angela"
                    android:layout_weight="0.8"
                    android:textColor="#2d2d2d"/>

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/timestamp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:text="01.35"
                    android:layout_weight="0.2"
                    android:textColor="#2d2d2d"/>

        </LinearLayout>
```

I'd suggest you look into ConstraintLayout as well. Might be better suited for your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it by setting the width to 0 and weight to 1 in your `username` text view, and extends its container's width to match parent:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent" // Extend the width to match parent
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/username"
            android:layout_width="0dp" // Set width to 0 and weight to 1
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="@angela"
            android:textColor="#2d2d2d" />

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/timestamp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="false"
            android:text="01.35"
            android:textColor="#2d2d2d" />
</LinearLayout>
```

A view with 0 width and weight of 1 in a horizontal `LinearLayout` will extend its width to a maximum but allow enough room for its next child view.